# how to get value from checkout form to payment gateway's integration part?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

this is the continuation of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246671/how-do-i-set-the-paid-amount-and-due-amount-manually-after-successful-transactio) from stackoverflow. i hope somebody can help me.

all i need is to pass a value of radio button from checkout form page to payment integration section.
my aim is to achieve partial payment if my order total is above 25000 Rs.

[image]

what i im trying to achieve is :-> does user wish to proceed with partial payment?

i don't want this value to be stored in database. i can neglect this data as soon as i forward the amount to payment gateway.
pls help me. im just a beginner.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to implement a payment method which supports the payment gateway and the part payment. Please refer to the documentation of the payment gateway and the payment method for the parameters you need to submit.

Comment: yes there is some recurring payment options from payment gateway itself. But. the requirement is : 30% of payment will be collected by online, due amount will be collected upon delivery of the product directly.Some how i had achieved this functionality by modifying another module